# PHP Leveral Applications InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do CRUD operations with database. But the problem is when I run the serve and trying to navigate to specific page I am getting following errors .

**(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
View [products.index] not found.**

Here is route.php

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
```

Here is the controller code .

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('products.index',compact('products'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
        ]);

        Product::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.show',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.edit',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
        ]);

        $product->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

Here is the output when i run the applications .
[image: al]

Comment: That means you do not have `index.blade.php` in `resources->views->products`

Comment: I have it @Gabriel

Comment: My blade template is located under the views folder

Comment: inside your views, you have to have another folder called products, inside that you have to have index.blade.php

Comment: Can you please check this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you do not have

> index.blade.php

inside

> resources->views->products

Make sure you have a folder name called `products` inside `views` folder, inside that place your `index.blade.php`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549378/php-laravel-applications-token-mismatch-exception-error/57549414?noredirect=1#comment101561632_57549414

Comment: Can you please check this question